# How to fix: " Getter not found: 'context'. "

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a flutter app that uses hero widget and inkwell widget, but when I try to use navigator.push to navigate to a new page I get this error:

```
Compiler message: lib/main.dart:238:25: Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
         Navigator.push(context ,MaterialPageRoute(
                        ^^^^^^^
```

I try to ask my question in some Telegram group and they answer me that I should define name 'context', but when I do it, I get this error and even navigator doesn't push to the new page.

```
...
Widget _buildPillItmes(String name, String imagePath, String count){
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
    child: new InkWell(
       onTap: () {
         //BuildContext context;
         Navigator.push(context ,MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => DetailsPage(heroTag: imagePath, pillName: name, pillCount: count)
         ));
       },
      child: new Row(
...
```

I expected to navigate to the new page but I get nothing except my first page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a method that returns a Widget. So I expect you are calling this method in your main widget's build method, right?

So, in this method's scope you don't have "context", you should pass it as a parameter. You only have the context inside build method.

In your main widget:

```
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // Here you have the context
    return new Center (
      child: this._buildPillItmes("name", "imagePath", 0, context), // Here you pass the context
    );
  }
}
```

Your method

```
...
Widget _buildPillItmes(String name, String imagePath, String count, BuildContext context){ // Here you expect the context
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
    child: new InkWell(
       onTap: () {
         // Now you have context and it should work
         Navigator.push(context ,MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => DetailsPage(heroTag: imagePath, pillName: name, pillCount: count)
         ));
       },
      child: new Row(
...
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to have **context** in scope, if you just define the name it will be null when you use it, in your main app you have a build method that takes the context as a parameter, so you can do something like this:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: _buildPillItmes("name", "image", "count", context),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildPillItmes(String name, String imagePath, String count, BuildContext context){
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
      child: new InkWell(
       onTap: () {
         Navigator.push(context ,MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => DetailsPage(heroTag: imagePath, pillName: name, pillCount: count)
         ));
       },
      child: new Row(
   ...
}
```

you just need to adapt this to your case and find the closest point where you have the context, probably you have it where you call **_buildPillItmes**

Answer (score 2):

i think they say like a param:

```
...
Widget _buildPillItmes(BuildContext context, String name, String imagePath, String count){
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
    child: new InkWell(
       onTap: () {
         Navigator.push(context ,MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => DetailsPage(heroTag: imagePath, pillName: name, pillCount: count)
         ));
       },
      child: new Row(
...
```

Hope i thelps.